# Executing "php app/console"-commands on the server

Tags: symfony, console

I uploaded my symfony-project (V2.5)  to the server (of my provider).
Now, I want to execute a command like

```
"$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug"
```

But I have no access to a CLI (command line interface).
How can I submit such a command?

Thx
Thomas

Comment: SSH? Some shared hosting does not allow to execute some funcions like exec(), check if you can use exec function

Comment: I can run exec() and passthru(). But I do not find the php.exe to create the console command. Any idea? (Installing of ConsoleBundle was fine but I have to execute the command "php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug" before - hen or egg-problem) Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have access to the server (via SSH for example), you can install
a bundle which allows you accessing the Symfony2 console via your browser.

Here is the one I'm using : [ConsoleBundle](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle).

Once installed, go to the console page (add `/_console` in URL after app_dev.php) and enter `assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` into the input field.