# How to run a command when a Symfony2 project is online (production mode)

Tags: symfony

How can you run a command on a Symfony2 command when it is online? I see that you need a command window but my project is going to be ran at a server that isn't mine, so how can I run commands on it? My host provides directadmin.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831572/executing-php-app-console-commands-on-the-server/24834516#24834516

Comment: Doesnt work: No route found for "GET /_console"

Comment: Are you using the dev front controller (app_dev.php) in the url ?

Comment: Yes I am, first time I'm deploying Symfony2 and geesh, how complicated can it be

Comment: Have you followed the installation instructions (https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle#installation) ? You need to do it on your local environment and then deploy it on server.

Comment: Yes I was already using console locally to run own defined commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65423/discussion-between-fidan-hakaj-and-harduser).

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle

If you have the "no route" error, try to access to

**yoursite/web/app_dev.php/_console/_console**

as the prefix defined in your routing_dev.yml will be added to the path defined in the Bundle's routing.yml

*routing_dev.yml*

```
_console:
    resource: "@CoreSphereConsoleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /_console
```

*#routing.yml from ConsoleBundle*

```
console:
    path:  /_console
```